# Facebook login in app xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

I have seen  many have been asking this question but I m confused...
 I want to integrate facebook login in my iphone app.Im need to provide login options i.e login with our website account or facebook login and use our app.But I have gone through google and found the tutorials providing facebook login feature with the total access (like post ,update etc) i.e login with facebook and do respective facebook activities.But I dont need all of them.I just need the functionality of login with user facebook account and access our app.And one more thing I have seen to download facebook sdk from git and copy FBConnect folder.But there is not such folder in it.I m confused

where can I find the best tutorial which suites my particular criteria..?

Please guide me in this aspect.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will help you,have a look  : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

You can download the facebook sdk from here : http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Then to bypass fb app and safari and to continue with your app you can change the code in Facebbok.m

```
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

to

```
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
```

in the method

```
   - (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions
     delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```

Comment: I have downloaded the sdk.But do I need to copy the whole sdk in my project by drag and drop ?

Comment: @Sindhia the one you just downloaded is the latest sdk, you might want to install that sdk before using it in your project.

Comment: Ya I have installed it also in documents folder.Now should I need to copy it in my project?

Comment: you can add the Facebook SDK for iOS Framework by dragging the FacebookSDK.framework folder from the SDK installation folder into the Frameworks section of your Project Navigator.

Here is the tutorial : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Comment: It contains all samples and sdkframework and all that.But I dont find any facebook.m folder in it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement to access your app login via facebook, firstly you should get the id(for example:19292868552) of user after succefully facebook login. And with the help of id you can uniquely identify the user in your database.

Comment: I have got app id ..Can u please suggest me a good tutorial related to it